# Every increasing function with some properties is the distribution of a random variable.

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $F:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ an increasing function s.t. $\lim_{x\to -\infty }F(x)=0$, $\lim_{x\to \infty }F(x)=1$ and $F$ is right continuous, then it's the distribution of some random variable.

---

The proof goes as follow : $\Omega =(0,1)$, $\mathcal F$ the Borel set of $(0,1)$ and $m$ the Lebesgue measure on $(0,1)$. Then, they prove that $$X(\omega )=\sup\{y\mid F(y)\leq \omega \}.$$
$X(\omega )$ is called the inverse function of $F$.

---

In my course and on wikipedia as well, it's written that if $F(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi}}\int_{-\infty }^x e^{-t^2/2}dt$, we can't construct explicitly the inverse function of $F$. My question is : since we just want to prove that $F$ is the distribution function of some r.v., why don't take $\Omega =\mathbb R$, $\mathcal F=\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ and $\mathbb P(A)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_A e^{-t^2/2}dt$. Then $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ is a probability space, and $X:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ defined by $X(\omega )=\omega $ is a normal distributed function with distribution $F$. Done !

**Question** So why using this "inverse function" on $((0,1),\mathcal B((0,1)),m)$ ? it really looks to complicate uselessly things..

Comment: Two points: $\int_{-\infty }^x e^{-t^2/2}dt \to \sqrt{2 \pi}\not = 1$ as $x \to +\infty$; and the inability to give a closed form for a function does not mean it fails to exist or is useless.  Indeed here you cannot write $F(x)$ or $X(w)$ in closed form but they are both useful. The quantile function of a normal distribution is used for example to calculate critical values for hypothesis tests.

Comment: I edited thank you. Yes, but I was wondering why in this theorem (since we want to prove only that $F$ is the distribution of a r.v.), why do we do so complicated, wherea there is a very easy way to solve this problem...

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to have Lebesgue measure as the basic probability measure. The single space $((0,1),\mathbb B,m)$ supports a random variable with any given distribution. It is more useful to work in a nice probability space than to work with a nice random variable.